# $_REQUEST php vulnerability

Tags: php, security, web

**This is a question about cybersecurity**

Hey everyone, I'm studying the `logical flaw` ( Authentication Bypass ) room with tryhackme.com
And I came across the `$_REQUEST` method in php.

**Before continuing, just to be clear... Here we are to make the website send the `reset password` to our own email**

the command we used `curl http://MACHINE_IP/customers/reset?email=robert%40acmeitsupport.thm' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'username=robert&email=attacker@hacker.com'`

first why we need the `username` in the `POST`?? and why we didn't use it in the `query string`?

second

the thing I can't understand How this should redirect the password to `attacker@hacker.com`

THM said

`The PHP $_REQUEST variable is an array that contains data received from the query string and POST data. If the same key name is used for both the query string and POST data, the application logic for this variable favours POST data fields rather than the query string, so if we add another parameter to the POST form, we can control where the password reset email gets delivered`

That means `$_REQUEST` php method will chose the `POST` rather than query string. I have no problem with this.
but if it really picked the `POST` then it should enter in the E-mail field: `attacker@hacker.com` ( Because it picked the POST way )
but that E-mail not exist! So it should say `Account not found from supplied email address`, Instead... it redirect the password to our E-mail !?

Thanks for reading.
room link in case you needed https://tryhackme.com/room/authenticationbypass

Comment: What you mean is URL parameter pollution (overriding values). But to make it more secure you should implement a nonce or CSRF token for the POST request.

Comment: "The Authentication Bypass room is for subscribers only."

Comment: "the $_REQUEST method" — It's an array stored in a [superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), not a method (nor any kind of function).

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the code, which you haven't shared, does something like this:

```
$reset_token = make_reset_token_for($_GET['email');
send_reset_token_to($reset_token, $_REQUEST['email']);
```

So it reads the email address to generate a reset token for from the query string (and updates the account information for that email address in the database) but then sends the reset token to the email address in the request body (which is the attacker's address and not the account owner's address).

This then lets the attacker use that reset token to change the account owner's password and then login to their account.

Comment: The code you shared not exist in room
Where did you get it from?

Comment: @Amr — As mentioned in a comment on your question, "The Authentication Bypass room is for subscribers only" which is why I had to reverse engineer an approximation of what it is doing from your description, hence the first sentence of this answer.

Comment: I know, and I shared all the commands in the room.

Comment: @Amr you shared what data gets send _to_ the server, but that tells us close to nothing about what the server then actually _does_ with this data.